# QGIS - Atlas : how to filter the pages of the Atlas?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, filter, atlas

I generated an atlas with plots in it and I wonder if I can choose what pages I want to keep in my atlas, using the page's number.
I have this list for my page.
[image]

For example, for the abreviation "ALD" I just want to show the page 3:ALD and so on for the other. For"ALL" I want to show 5: ALL ....

I have already tried the filter :*@atlas_featurenumber IN ('3','5')*

But I have this message : "Atlas : no matches found"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the @atlas_featurenumber I used the @id and it's worked in my case.